# Creating an HTML5 WYSIWYG: should I save the image dataURL in database?

Tags: mysql, html, wysiwyg, data-url

I'm currently writing an HTML5 WYSIWYG using Google Closure Library and I'm providing users to just drag and drop the image file to contenteditable field with text to add an image.

So I have two ways to store these images:

**1.** Retrieve the data URL from dropped file, create an IMG tag, set the retrieved data URL as value of attribute SRC of this image and insert this IMG tag into editor's field. When user will submit the form I'll just save all retrieved HTML in my MySQL database and will able render his text with images later.

**2.** Upload the dropped image to my server and save it as regular file.
Then the server will answer like:
"image saved, its URL is http://example.com/images/uploaded-image.png".
After that I will perform the steps similar to my item 1 (create an IMG tag with attribute src="http://example.com/images/uploaded-image.png" and insert it into editable field).

**The first way** will **load database more** because it requires to store an image dataUrl in database field together with text. But it makes image adding more easy and fast, so it improves the user's experience.

**The second way** will **load database less** because the images will stored separately (in the file system), but this way requires more requests to the server and some processor time on each image adding into text within the WYSIWYG. Also it will not show an immediate result to user so the user will need to wait when his image will uploaded, what will make user's experience worse.

I need the help to understand which way is more preferable in my case considering all pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

**Another way** is to store not only images but complete HTML with images in one file. And use the database for storing a link to the HTML file. Then setup Nginx and get the best performance. IMHO if your application is WYSIWYG then the content should be loaded and laid out completely in the browser before editing.

Comment: This solution doesn't looks appropriate since I'll not be able to search through the text same effectively like if I'll be using the database as storage.